# A variation of boy-or-girl paradox

Tags: probability, python, conditional-probability, paradox

I was working on this problem but the extra information supplied seems so superfluous and I'm trying to figure out if it is meaningful, and how it is meaningful.

**Given:**
This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=go3xtDdsNQM&t=354s) has presented two boy-or-girl paradoxes.

**Find:**
What is the probability for one of the children to be a girl given that;

1. One of them is a boy,
2. One of them is a boy born on Tuesday.

**Analysis:**
The **first** one is relatively trivial and well explained (the answer is $2/3 \sim 66\%)$; let's focus on the second one.

For the **second** one, the approach presented in the video is to expand the sample space to include the day of birth and calculate the probability with simple counting. The resulting probability is estimated to be $\sim 52\%$, which I have reproduced using a simple Monte Carlo calculation.

Moreover, I have also calculated the probability for one of the children to be a girl, given that one of the two children is a boy born on Tuesday with a thumb raised when born (equal probability for each finger). The resulting probability is $\sim 50.7\%$. It seems that with more and more irrelevant information included, the result approaches the usual $50\%$. It feels like some sort of dimensional diluting (I am not sure that's the right word).

**The problem I have:**
I don't have a clear picture of why such seemingly irrelevant information could impact the analysis. Any help would be welcomed.

**How I have engaged it:**
You may find the code I used as shown.

```
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

np.random.seed(42)
N = 100000

N_a_boy_born_on_Tue_and_with_a_thumb = 0
N_a_boy_born_on_Tue_and_with_a_thumb_and_a_girl = 0
for _ in tqdm(range(N)):
    first_child_sex = np.random.choice(['M', 'F'])
    first_child_day_of_birth = np.random.choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
    first_child_day_finger_raise = np.random.choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
    second_child_sex = np.random.choice(['M', 'F'])
    second_child_day_of_birth = np.random.choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
    second_child_day_finger_raise = np.random.choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

    if ((first_child_sex == 'M' and first_child_day_of_birth == 2 and first_child_day_finger_raise == 0) or
        (second_child_sex == 'M' and second_child_day_of_birth == 2 and second_child_day_finger_raise == 0)):

        N_a_boy_born_on_Tue_and_with_a_thumb += 1

        if first_child_sex == 'F' or second_child_sex == 'F':

            N_a_boy_born_on_Tue_and_with_a_thumb_and_a_girl += 1

probability = N_a_boy_born_on_Tue_and_with_a_thumb_and_a_girl / N_a_boy_born_on_Tue_and_with_a_thumb * 100
print(f"The probability a child is a girl given a boy is born on Tue and rasing a thumb is {probability}%.")

N_a_boy_born_on_Tue = 0 
N_a_boy_born_on_Tue_and_a_girl = 0 
for _ in tqdm(range(N)):
    first_child_sex = np.random.choice(['M', 'F'])
    first_child_day_of_birth = np.random.choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) 
    second_child_sex = np.random.choice(['M', 'F'])
    second_child_day_of_birth = np.random.choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) 

    if ((first_child_sex == 'M' and first_child_day_of_birth == 2) or
        (second_child_sex == 'M' and second_child_day_of_birth == 2)):

        N_a_boy_born_on_Tue += 1

        if first_child_sex == 'F' or second_child_sex == 'F':

            N_a_boy_born_on_Tue_and_a_girl += 1

probability = N_a_boy_born_on_Tue_and_a_girl / N_a_boy_born_on_Tue * 100 
print(f"The probability a child is a girl given a boy is born on Tue is {probability}%.")

N_a_boy_born_on_any_day = 0 
N_a_boy_born_on_any_day_and_a_girl = 0 
for _ in tqdm(range(N)):
    first_child_sex = np.random.choice(['M', 'F'])
    first_child_day_of_birth = np.random.choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) 
    second_child_sex = np.random.choice(['M', 'F'])
    second_child_day_of_birth = np.random.choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) 

    if ((first_child_sex == 'M' and first_child_day_of_birth in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) or
        (second_child_sex == 'M' and second_child_day_of_birth in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])):

        N_a_boy_born_on_any_day += 1

        if first_child_sex == 'F' or second_child_sex == 'F':

            N_a_boy_born_on_any_day_and_a_girl += 1

probability = N_a_boy_born_on_any_day_and_a_girl / N_a_boy_born_on_any_day * 100 
print(f"The probability a child is a girl given a boy is born on any day is {probability}%.")
```

Comment: Could you summarize what is said in the video? It is likely that people wouldn't be interested in watching all of it, hence won't answer your question.

Comment: I have added a brief summary of the approach used in the video. The main focus of my question is why the probability is affected by seemingly irreverent information, which is verified with Monte Carlo sampling.

Comment: I have come across this entry [here][1], which answers my question.


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_Girl_paradox#Information_about_the_child

Comment: You need a clear question.  What exactly are you asking?  Are you asking if the supplied information is actually important, or how to prove whether it is such?

Comment: @PeterPang - could you make an answer that shows what you found valuable and how it you can approach questions like it in the future?  You are allowed to answer your own questions, and I don't know that CV has any engaging this particular paradox.

Comment: The Wikipedia article identified by @Peter concludes, "The moral of the story is that these probabilities do not just depend on the known information, but on how that information was obtained."  That's precisely why we are obliged to respond to so many abstractly formulated questions with comments that ask people to explain how they obtained their data!